# Rails has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I am trying to use the `has_many :through` relation in rails to return a set of product features. Please see this gist for the models: https://gist.github.com/4572661

I know how to do this using the `ProductFeature` model directly, but I really do not want to have to interact with it directly.

I want to be able to do this:

`features = Product.features`

So it returns:

`[id: 1, name: 'Colour', value: 'Blue'],
[id: 2, name: 'Size', value: 'M'],
[id: 3, name: 'Shape', value: 'Round']`

But I can only get it to return:

`[id: 1, name: 'Colour'],
[id: 2, name: 'Size'],
[id: 3, name: 'Shape']`

I was using [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many :through` is designed to regard the `join table` as nothing more than that.

Any columns on the join will be ignored from the association.

As such we have to use `product_features`

```
product.product_features(include: :feature)
```

Thereby we can say

```
product.product_features(include: :feature).each do |pf|
  feature = pf.feature

  name = feature.name
  value = pf.value
end
```

---

If you use this type of thing a lot, I'd be inclined to do something like this;

```
class Product
  # always eager load the feature
  has_many :product_features, include: :feature
end

class ProductFeature
  # delegate the feature_name
  delegate :name, to: :feature
end
```

Comment: I realised after I posted that I'd need to do something else to achieve what I wanted, and your answer seems to be exactly what I need! I shall try what you've provided and accept tomorrow! Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks Matthew, I achieved it with the following: https://gist.github.com/4577958